# Martingale concept. Can I always win in a fair game?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Suppose the following game: You start with $1€$.

1. Toss a coin. If it is obtained "head", you win $1€$, and stop the game; otherwise, you lose $1€$, and continue in step 2.
2. Toss a coin. If it is obtained "head", you win $2€$, and stop the game; otherwise, you lose $2€$, and continue in step 3.
3. Toss a coin. If it is obtained "head", you win $4€$, and stop the game; otherwise, you lose $4€$, and continue in step 4.

$\quad \cdots$

$\quad n$. Toss a coin. If it obtained "head", you win $2^{n-1}€$, and stop the game; otherwise, you lose $2^{n-1}€$, and continue in step $n+1$.

$\quad \cdots$

Note that, in the end, you will have $2€$.

Let's analyze this game in a probabilistic way. Define $\xi_i=1$ if you obtain "head" in step $i$; and $-1$ otherwise. We have $P(\xi_i=1)=P(\xi_i=-1)=1/2$. Let $H_n=2^{n-1}$ if $\xi_1=\ldots=\xi_{n-1}=-1$; and $0$ otherwise. Then the money we have at time $n$ is 
$$ Z_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^n H_i\xi_i. $$
It turns out that $\{Z_n\}_{n\geq0}$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration generated by $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots$

I cannot understand this. If a martingale represents a fair game (you do not know if you will win or lose), how is it possible in this case that you win for sure $2€$ in the end?

Comment: Money has a demenishing return value curve.

What does 2$ mean if you already got 1 million?

One could argue that for high values 2 equals 0

Comment: You need unlimited credit and an opponent who will accept unlimited bets.  Even then, for a fair coin, your expected position after $n$ tosses (by which time you may have already stopped or still be playing) will be the amount you started with so long as $n$ is finite.

Comment: Reminiscent of the St Petersburg paradox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a process where $X_{t+1}=X_t+2^t$ with probability $1/2$ and $X_t-2^t$ with probability $1/2$ and each win/loss is independent. You define the stopping time $\tau$ to be the first time that you win the game. Then if $X_0=0$ then $X_\tau=1$. Thus you can always guarantee winning something even though the game is fair.

The issue is, to play this way, you have to be allowed to play the game for an arbitrarily long time, and you have to be allowed to go into an arbitrarily large amount of debt (or come into the casino with infinite money). If either of those conditions is omitted then you introduce games where you ultimately lose, and the average drops back to zero.

The theorem that ensures this is called the optional stopping theorem, and it has *nontrivial* hypotheses about the properties of the stopping time.

Incidentally, the betting strategy you are describing is called the martingale betting strategy; to my understanding it is the origin of the word "martingale" in mathematics. Even in view of the above, it's not as bad as it sounds. Say you cap yourself at 10 losses before you go home. Then with a probability $1023/1024$, you win one money unit. It's just that the rest of the time, you lose 1024 money units.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to ask you about the use of the stopping time $\tau$ here. My teacher proved that $\{Z_{\inf\{n,\tau\}}\}_{n\geq0}$ is a martingale. If I am not wrong, I think that $Z_{\inf\{n,\tau\}}=Z_n$ for all $n$, so why introducing the stopping time $\tau$?

Comment: @user372906 You are wrong there. If $\tau=10$, say, then $\inf \{ n,\tau \}$ is $n$ until $n=10$ and then it stays $10$ forever.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, $Z_{10}=2$, and $Z_n=2$ for all $n>10$ (by definition of $H$), so $Z_{\inf\{n,\tau\}}=Z_n$?

Comment: No. The point is that the original $Z_n$ is a process which "plays the game forever". $Z_{\inf \{ n,\tau \}}$ is a different process which stops playing after winning a game.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you for your explanation :)

Comment: They're not the same, that's what I just said. $Z_n$ is a process which plays the game forever. $Z_{\inf \{ n,\tau \}}$ is a process which plays the game until it wins and then stops playing.

Comment: I had changed the comment before.

Comment: with 50% chance of winning it shouldn't take too long...

Comment: @saturatedexpo Except that with some positive probability it *does*. Of course it has finite mean (indeed all finite moments), but then the second case of the optional stopping theorem (as stated on Wikipedia) requires control on the increments of the process, which you don't have in this scenario.

Comment: @Ian what do you mean with "finite mean"?

Comment: @saturatedexpo The number of games played before winning the first game is a geometric random variable with parameter $1/2$. Such a random variable has a finite expected value (namely $2$).